# Shortcode no longer displaying custom post type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I created a `testimonial` post type to display reviews I have inputted on my site. then I created two functions to create a `testimonial block` that would display these reviews on certain pages with a shortcode. At first all was working fine but then as I added more and more testimonials they stopped displaying and I have not been able to figure out why. Does anyone have any experience with this. See the two functions include in my `functions.php` below:

```
//Testimonial widget
function sal_testimonials_widget($atts){

    //shortcode options
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'section_title' => 'Testimonials',
                'custom_location_filter' => '',

            ), $atts
        )
    );

    //post data
    $filter_ids = '';
    $post_type = '';

    //initial variables
    $location_filter = '';


    $custom_filters_added = ($custom_location_filter !== '' ? true : false);

    if($custom_filters_added){
        if($custom_location_filter !== ''){
            $filter_ids = $custom_location_filter;
            $post_type = 'Locations';
        }

    }else{
        global $post;
        $post_type = $post->post_type;
        $filter_ids= $post->ID;
    }

    $output = '<div class="testimonials-block-container">';
    $output.= sal_testimonials_block($post_type, true, $filter_ids, $section_title);
    $output.= '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('testimonials_widget', 'sal_testimonials_widget');

////Testimonials block
function sal_testimonials_block($testimonial_type, $enabled, $id, $section_title){
      $testimonial_args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => $init_amount_to_display, 
        'offset'=> 0, 
        'post_type' => 'testimonials', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    $testimonials_id_array = array();

    $testimonials = get_posts( $testimonial_args );
    $current_post_id = get_the_ID();
    $current_post_type=get_post_type($current_post_ID);
    $output.='<div class="testimonial-slideshow">';
    if($testimonials):
        foreach ($testimonials as $item) {

            $location = get_field('location_associated_with_testimonial', $item );  
            $city= get_field('city', $location);
            $state= get_field('state', $location);
            $author=get_field('testimonial_authors_name', $item);
            $universal=get_field('is_universal', $item);
            $date=get_field('testimonial_date', $item);
            $customer_city=get_field('customer_city', $item);

            if($location==$current_post_id){                
                $output.='<div class="testimonial-slide">';             
                $output.= '<div class="testimonial-item">';
                $output.= '<q class="testimonial">' . get_post_field('post_content', $item) . '</q>';           
                $output.= ( $author ? '<div class="testimonial-author">' . $author . '</div>' : '' );           

                $output.='<div class="testimonial-location">';
                if(strlen($customer_city)>1){$output.=$customer_city;}
                else{$output.= $city . ', ' . $state;}
                $output.='</div>';
                $output.= ( $date ? '<div class="testimonial-date">' . $date . '</div>' : '' );
                $output.= '</div>';
                $output.='</div>';                  
            }
            if($testimonial_type!='locations'&&$universal==true){               
                $output.='<div class="testimonial-slide">';             
                $output.= '<div class="testimonial-item">';
                $output.= '<q class="testimonial">' . get_post_field('post_content', $item) . '</q>';           
                $output.= ( $author ? '<div class="testimonial-author">' . $author . '</div>' : '' );
                $output.='<div class="testimonial-location">';
                if(strlen($customer_city)>1){$output.=$customer_city;}
                else{$output.= $city . ', ' . $state;}
                $output.='</div>';
                $output.= ( $date ? '<div class="testimonial-date">' . $date . '</div>' : '' );
                $output.= '</div>';
                $output.='</div>';                  
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        $output.='</div>';   

    endif;

    return $output;



}
```

I also used some JavaScript (JQuery) to make a slider to display multiple testimonials on a single page. See below:

```
/*
     * Location Single Page Testimonial Slideshow
     * Add slick slider to the testimonial section of the lcoation page
    */
    if ($(".testimonial-slideshow").length > 0) {
        $(".testimonial-slideshow").slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            fade: false,
            cssEase: "ease",
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 8000,
            prevArrow:
                '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>,',
            nextArrow:
                '<div class="slick-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>',
            draggable: false,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        draggable: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

I tried flushing the rewrite rules in multiple areas for the custom post type but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: It could be the data in one of the testimonials. Check for error messages both on the server and in the developer console. Try reducing the number of testimonials and increase it by 1 until you find the one that breaks it.

Comment: @aynber What type of data do you think could break it? Each testimonial was individually created manually.

Comment: It's really hard to tell. It could be a rogue character or code. If it works with one or two but breaks after a certain amount or certain testimonial, it's usually something within that testimonial that you may have to escape out.

Comment: @aynber also what is strange is that when I add a new testimonial. it will display with the shortcode at first but will eventually disappear from view a few page refreshes later.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my main error. In my second PHP function `sal_testimonials_block()` I had:

```
 $testimonial_args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => $init_amount_to_display, 
        'offset'=> 0, 
        'post_type' => 'testimonials', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
```

I realized I never defined `$init_amount_to_display`, I'm not sure how it was able to work at all originally, but I changed the above block of code to the below and it seems to work fine now.

```
$testimonial_args = $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'testimonials'
    );
```